# eclipse android Logcat not showing 'Saved Filters' panel

Tags: android, eclipse, filter, logcat

I'm using eclipse-Luna and android sdk. I'm using emulator-4.0. I can see logcat messages but 'Saved filters' panel in logcat is gone. I dig in eclipse-Windows options. But i didn't see there any logcat-filters customization. How can i get it back ?

[image: logcat snapshot]

Comment: Toggle the button next to `clear log`

Comment: have You used a new phone? I had the problem with Huawei Ascned Mate 7.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toggle the button next to `Clear Log`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on the third icon from verbose dropdown as shown in image.

[image]